Terminal escape sequence to store screen?
I am working in a terminal and drawing to the screen with escape sequences, as a character-based user interface (CHUI)
It seems that I have seen in other CHUI programs that a window will pop up, and when closed, the underlying text is again displayed.  It is not clear to me if this is the program simply redrawing the underlying characters, or if the terminal is helping with this.
My actual program is a debugger which displays content at the top of the terminal, while letting the main program continue to output line-by-line to the bottom of the screen.  I would like to be able to display a help menu or screen taking up much of the display, and then return back to prior display -- complete with the main program's output.
I can't just redraw what the main program output, since that is outside my control.  So I hoped that I could tell the terminal to save off the current display, then draw my help screen, and then have the terminal restore the display.
I have asked chatGPT and I keep getting erroneous answers that indicate that "esc[s" will save the current screen.  But from what I can tell, this actually only saves the cursor location, not the screen.  And the sample scripts that the AI gives don't actually work as they suggest.  I have tried them on a Mac with iTerm and on Windows with PuTTY.
My suspicion is that older terminals did not have extra memory hanging around waiting to be filled with saved terminal pages.  But modern terminals surely must have this ability.  But I can't seem to find documentation of it, despite my searching.
tl;dr -- what escape sequence will store off entire display of screen, and what sequence will later restore it?

I have figured some things out on my own:

There is not a way to save off the screen and later restore it.
When programs seem to be doing this (e.g. vim, htop etc), what they are actually doing is switching to an alternative buffer.  When done, they return to the primary buffer.  And doing this effects restoring the prior contents of the screen.

I found discussion of this here.
The syntax is ESC[?1049h and ESC[?1049l  -- here h activates the alternate buffer and l returns to normal mode.  Other similar codes are 1047 and 1048.  But apparently they are older and have less functionality.
The fact that this code starts with ESC[? apparently indicates that this is a private setmode, and functionality may vary across various terminals.
Here is another resorce: https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/vtfeatures/.  Search for DECSET and click the "more" link to expand the listing.

Did you figure out how to get which buffer alternate/normal is currently active?
